# How to update only one Fragment (page/item) of a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have a `ViewPager` with a `PagerTitleStrip` which is filled with a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` which is filled with fragments which contains just a single text. These texts are stored in a array of texts with 11 positions, one per each fragment of the ViewPager.

The problem is that some of the texts in the array are being updated each X seconds, so I must find the way of update ONLY the fragment corresponding to that text. When I update the array of texts, I know the position of that array, so i know the number of the fragment inside the viewpager which must be updated. but there is a problem, I don't know a way to update just that fragment.

I only know how to update all of them at same time, using `notifyDataSetChanged()` and returning `POSITION_NONE` at `getItemPosition` of my `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. This strategy does not work, because all of them are updated and the same time and this generates an abnormal behaviour (scroll is lost in the page you are seeing, if you are swipping between pages when the notifyDataSet function is called you loss your swip movement, etc...)

How can I solve this?

This is my current source code:

This is my adapter:

```
public class CollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public CollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment = new ObjectFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ObjectFragment.ARG_TEXT, children[i]);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return infoTitlesArray.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return infoTitlesArray[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

The ViewPager which has the problem:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            style="@style/CustomPagerTitleStrip"/>
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Layout of the fragment:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarSize="5dip"
    style="@style/CustomScrollBar">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        style="@style/CustomTextView"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Have you tried an Event?

Comment: Can you not get an instance of a Fragment from the Adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Fragment of a ViewPager can be found by using tag,

**In Activity**

```
Fragment fragmentToShow = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
              mCollectionPagerAdapter.getFragmentTag(R.id.pager, position));
```

**In FragmentStatePagerAdapter**

```
 public String getFragmentTag(int viewPagerId, int fragmentPosition) {
    // This is the format in which FragmentStatePagerAdapter internally set's  the fragment tag.
    return "android:switcher:" + viewPagerId + ":" + fragmentPosition;
  }
```

Comment: Can you adapt your sample of code to my source code? I dont know how to adapt it. Also, once you have the fragment... ¿how to update it with the new text? How to know which position of the array is the correct for that fragment? thank you

Comment: Updated sample of code to your source code, when do you want to update this new text? is it on page change?

Comment: Srry don't understand your sample code. ¿How is suposed it will fit to my problem? What is suposed should I do with that fragment one i have it? I dont know how to repaint a fragment. ¿Exist something similar to invalidate()?Also seems a little hacker that way of get the fragment. Is not a safer way to do it?

Comment: PD: te text is updated once each second, with new data.